# Jquery DataTables 1.10 not working in IE 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, datatables

I have a page, which uses the DataTables plugin to render JSOn data to a ASP.NET application.

Everything is working fine in all other browsers apart from IE9, for which I get the following error when the page loads.

[image]

Drilling into the code within Visual Studio I can see that cells is undefined, and this is causing the length piece of code to blow up.

[image]

My question is, How can i fix this so it works in IE9?

Comment: I would like to see the markup and how you initialise the dataTable.  It is not a known error, if it _is_ an IE-specific dataTables error, so it would be nice to try to reproduce the above error.

Comment: Hi David, i'll spend some time putting this together, once i've finished my afternoon meetings.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the same with Keeping Browser compatibility mode on.

In your browser Go to , Tools > compatibility view settings.

you can select option to view your page in compatible view.

see if it solves your issue.

Comment: no, infact I dont want/need to do this as it messes up all the CSS/JS work on the page.